# UWP Device Manufacturer

Tags: uwp, device

I am attempting to get the manufacturer of a radio device (on a Windows system). I retrieve the radio devices and look for the System.Devices.DeviceManufacturer property type. But it is not in the collection. I can see the radio active in device manager and when I check it's properties there is a manufacturer. So my question -- should the same manufacturer property exist in the device property list  that correlates to the manufacturer displayed in the device manager properties dialog. If not -- is it possible to get the manufacturer -- and how do I do this?

Peter

Answer (score 0):

To get the Manufacturer, you need to use the [Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Pnp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.pnp) API. The usage of PnpObject is similar to that of the [Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Enumeration) API. When you create the PnpObject with one of it's static methods, you need to add "System.Devices.Manufacturer" to the list of properties like the following:

```cs
private PnpObjectWatcher pnpObjectWatcher = null;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> properties = new List<string>();
    properties.Add("System.Devices.Manufacturer");
    pnpObjectWatcher = PnpObject.CreateWatcher(PnpObjectType.DeviceContainer,properties);
    pnpObjectWatcher.Added += PnpObjectWatcher_Added;
    pnpObjectWatcher.Start();
}

private void PnpObjectWatcher_Added(PnpObjectWatcher sender, PnpObject args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(args.Properties["System.Devices.Manufacturer"]);
}
```

Note that the PnpObjectType must be of type DeviceContainer, otherwise the manufacturer name cannot be obtained.